# Multiple constraints on parameter of a generic function

Tags: swift, generic-programming

Reading about generic functions in Swift, I see that it is possible to put some constraints on a parameter by requiring, that it is a subclass of a given class C, or that it implements a given protocol P.
But I wonder if there is a way to require both at the same time. I haven't found anything about that yet.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually You can do that.

If you have seen `Codable` in swift it is actually `Decodable` and  `Encodable`

```
 typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable
```

So in some function if you are using generic T as Codable

```
struct StructOfCodable<T:Codable>: Codable {
     ....
}
```

Here is example

```
protocol Test {}
class TClass {

}

typealias Common = Test & TClass

func generic <T:Common>(method:T) {

}
```

Another way is protocol and class both can have super class. So you can create common protocol

like

```
protocol CommonInProtocolAndStruct { }

protocol ProtocolUsedAsConstraint:CommonInProtocolAndStruct {} 

struct StructUsedAsConstraint:CommonInProtocolAndStruct {}
```

And any method you can use  `CommonInProtocolAndStruct` as generic constraint

Answer (score 1):

You can add any number of type constraints using a `where` clause. Examples:

```
import UIKit

func f<T>(t: T) where T: UIView, T: Encodable {}

class C<T> where T: UIView, T: Encodable {}
```